# Order of execution of commands in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am writing a program in scheme, that uses recursion to walk through the list, and stop at certain pointer, when counter reaches a certain number N

```
(define (functX N lst)
  (define counter 1)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(negative? N) empty]
    [(< (length lst) N) empty]
    [(<= counter N) ((set! counter (+ counter 1))(cons (first lst) (functX N (rest lst)))))]
    [else empty]))
```

I don't understand, why the second line from the bottom is giving me trouble: the error I am getting is **"procedure application: expected procedure, given: '(1) (no arguments)"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have it enclosed in parentheses twice. Expressions in Scheme have the form `(func-expr arg-expr ...)`, so the first expression must evaluate into a function. So if you did:

```
(define (f n) n)
((f 5))
```

It would evaluate `(f 5)` then it would try and evaluate `(5)` which is an error.

**Edit:** Some clarification.

You have the following enclosed in brackets twice:

```
((set! counter (+ counter 1))(cons (first lst) (functX N (rest lst)))))
```

So first it evaluates `set!` and reduces down to (where `n` is a number):

```
(n (cons ...))
```

`cons` is then evaluated along with its arguments (where `x` is the result):

```
(n x)
```

It then tries to apply the argument `x` to the function `n`, but since `n` is a number this results in an error. If you wanted to do two separate computations and only return the value of one, you can use `begin`.

```
(begin (set! counter (+ counter 1)) (cons (first lst) (functX N (rest lst))))
```

**Update:**

Here is a function that appears to do what you want without voodoo (since mutation is evil).

```
(define (take n xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) empty]
    [(negative? n) empty]
    [(eq? n 0) empty]
    [else (cons (first xs) (take (- n 1) (rest xs)))]))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if (f 5) returned a function ((f 5)) would actually to execute it. Just to show that a nested function call isn't always an error.

Comment: I am sorry, this is answer adds more confusion

Comment: You mean (set! counter (+ counter 1)) is twice parenthesized ?

Comment: @user465292: There, I added some clarification.

Comment: @user465292: I added a better version of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider decrementing N in the recursive call and removing the `counter` variable altogether.

Comment: My idea is that counter should increase as we go along the list, and then counter reaches N, it stops !

Comment: If you use N to count down you'll be able to avoid a separate counter variable and the program will become much cleaner and stateless.

Comment: Don't use set! unless you have to, simply recurse using (functX (- N 1) (rest lst))